# String , char double convert going along string

Tags: java

so say if i had a string like "3+3-1*2/3="
how would i go through the string looking at each character and if its a number turn it to a double then if not turn it to a char??

Comment: I have no idea what is being turned into what and when and who is the why of what or whom of how?

Comment: my homework is to get the input then calculate it, so you first input 3 then press enter then press + then enter then 3 etc, i'm just interested how you would do it this way

Comment: Appears straight forward to me, what are you having trouble with?

Comment: You could use a library which does the calculation for you, but that might not get any marks. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse through the String using a loop.  For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < mystring.length(); i++) {
    char character = mystring.charAt(i);
    // do stuff with character
}
```

You can check if it is a decimal character by using [Character.isDigit(char)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29).

You can convert a string to an integer using [parseInt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).

Answer (score 4):

iterate over the string, and for each character use Character.isDigit(char c) to determine if it is a digit or not.

after you try this, if you need some more help - write what have you tried and I'll try to further help you.

Comment: Numbers can include '.' which is not a digit. They can also inlcude '-' which can be negative or a minus (same with '+')

Comment: @Peter you are right.It was not clear (to me at least) from the initial question what exactly does he need. after he'll try to make some initial tryout, I'll edit and refer to this point, and of course specific problems he'll have. thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Double.valueOf(String s) will throw an exception if the given String can not be parsed to a double.

Answer (score 0):

```
String currentSubstring = "";
for (int index = 0; index < myString.length(); index++) {
    char next = myString.charAt(index);
    if ((next >= '0' && next <= '9') || next == '.') {
        currentSubstring += next;
    }
    else {
        if (! "".equals(currentSubstring)) {
            System.out.println("Found a number:  " + Double.parseDouble(currentSubstring));
            currentSubstring = "";
        }
        System.out.println("Found a character:  " + next);
    }
}
//in case the string ended with some numbers
if (! "".equals(currentSubstring)) {
    System.out.println("Found a number:  " + Double.parseDouble(currentSubstring));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will iterate thru your string and splits it into chunks of digits and `.`, or single operators. Note that operators are handled one-by one.

```
String input = "3+3-1*2/3=";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9.]+|[^0-9.])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

while (m.find ()) {
    String chunk = m.group();
    char c = chunk.charAt(0);
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9' || c == '.') then {
        // numbers
    } else {
        // operator
    }
}
```

If you want to respect precedence you should reorder your chunks to [Polish form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation), then do the calculations.